# Question about the intervals in the lebesgue measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In one book I saw that they constructed the lebesgue measure via semialgebras etc, starting with the intervals $(a,b]$, a and b is finite, and $(-\infty, b]$, and $(a,\infty)$.

But please take a look at this wikipedia article.:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Definition

Here they say they construct it using all closed, open and semiclosed intervals, I assume they are $(a,b),(a,b],[a,b),[a,b]$. But is infinity included here? Or will you get the measure without thinking about infinity?

They do something of the same in a new book I am reading. They start defining a set with all type of intervals. But they do not say if infinity can be one of the endpoints. But then they start to talk about functions that are finite on the set. And the length function is such a function, and so this "says" that we only look at final intervals?

**Basically, if you are constructing the Lebesgue measure, and you look at the 4 intervals open, closed and semi-closed, is it implicitly assumed that all of them are finite?**

UPDATE:
Was asked about what book I used in the comments, it was Principles of mathematical analysis 3rd. edition, by rudin. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: No, it should not be implicitly assumed. It should be spelled out by the author of the book. Maybe they failed to do this, or maybe you did not notice. Please add a reference to the book you are reading.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Hello, it is Principles of Mathematical analysis, by Rudin. 3rd edition, page 302.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat added a picture also

Comment: It is the same problem in the wiki article, they do not say if the sets used in construction of the measure(the open intervals), can be infinite?

Comment: The wiki says that $l(I) = b-a$; when people write this, it's safe to guess they think of $a,b$ as finite. I never  read that chapter of Rudin's book, but my guess is that he's going to talk about $\prod (b_i-a_i)$ soon, which will be a clue that $a_i,b_i$ are finite.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Ok, thanks, yes he talks about that product. But since everything is noneagtive, that product could also be ininity I thought. But he doesn't say anything about the case of zero times infinity etc., so I can probably do as you say and assume everything is finite then.